# How to download a pdf file from oracle database using servlets without corrupting the file?

Tags: java, servlets, oracle11g

I have a servlet in which I retrieve a pdf file from oracle database based on id and write it into the response stream. But when I try to do that, the downloaded file is corrupted and has zero file size. Adobe reader gives an error saying that "Adobe could not open "myfile.pdf" because it is either not a supported type...".

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.sql.Blob;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;

    import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



    @MultipartConfig( fileSizeThreshold = 1024 * 1024,
    maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 5, maxRequestSize = 1024 * 1024 * 5 * 5)

    public class DBFileDownloadServlet extends HttpServlet {


        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        // size of byte buffer to send file
        private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;   



        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            // get file id from URL's parameters
            String course_code = request.getParameter("course_code");

            Connection conn = null; // connection to the database

            try {
                        // connects to the database
                Connection con = JDBCfile.getOracleConnection();


                // queries the database
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM course_syllabus WHERE course_code = ?";

             PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                    statement.setString(1, course_code);

                ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

            if (result.next()) {
                    // gets file name and file blob data

            String fileName = result.getString("file_name");
                    Blob blob = result.getBlob("syllabus_file");
                    InputStream inputStream = blob.getBinaryStream();
                    int fileLength = inputStream.available();

                    System.out.println("fileLength = " + fileLength);

                    ServletContext context = getServletContext();

                    // sets MIME type for the file download
                    String mimeType = context.getMimeType(fileName);
                    if (mimeType == null) {        
                        mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
                    }              

                    // set content properties and header attributes for the response
                    response.setContentType(mimeType);
                    response.setContentLength(fileLength);
                    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
                    String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", fileName);
                    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

                    // writes the file to the client
                    OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                    int bytesRead = -1;

                    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }

                    inputStream.close();
                    outStream.close();             
                } else {
                    // no file found
                    response.getWriter().print("File not found for the file id: " + course_code);  
                }
            }catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                response.getWriter().print("SQL Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                response.getWriter().print("IO Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                JDBCfile.cleanup(con,statement); //closes connection      
            }
        }
    }
```

course_syllabus table has columns:  course_code varchar,file_name varchar,syllabus_file (blob)

everything executes perfectly but the file I download has zero byte and nothing to read. I am new to servlet programming, Anybody having any clue?
Please post a working solution too. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is here:

```
int fileLength = inputStream.available();
```

available() does not return the total number of bytes in the stream.  It just returns how many bytes can be read without blocking.  From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29):

> Note that while some implementations of `InputStream` will return the total number of bytes in the stream, many will not. **It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream.**

Use [Blob.length()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Blob.html#length%28%29) instead:

```
long fileLength = blob.length();
// ...
response.setContentLengthLong(fileLength);
```

Another problem is your error handling.  Do not act like the method succeeded if it did not succeed.  You *want* the HTTP call to return an error, if your method could not successfully obtain the file.

First, remove the `catch (IOException ex)` block.  If there is an IOException, you want it to propagate, so the HTTP call will fail as it should.

The other two blocks need to propagate their errors:

```
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    throw new ServletException(ex);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    throw new ServletException(e);
```

Similarly, you want to do more than just print "File not found" when the ResultSet is empty.  There is an HTTP response code intended specifically to indicate that an HTTP request failed because the requested resource was not found:

```
if (result.next()) { 
    // ...
} else {
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
    response.getWriter().print("File not found for the file id: " + course_code);  
}
```